# Let Service know when a method have been run

Tags: android, service, void

Is there any way I can make a service that will be noticed when a specific method have been runned in another app, I already know the package name, class, and name of the method?

Answer (score 0):

The other app is welcome to call `startService()` to send a command to your service when "a specific method have been runned".

However, you cannot do this from outside, in the manner that you are suggesting.